# Where Padma Purana says that a parrot can learn to chant the Hare Krishna maha mantra?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, mantras, padma-purana

There is a verse in the Padma Purana which says that a pet parrot can learn to chant *Hare Krishna ...*

Where is that verse located in the Padma Purana?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23667/please-provide-all-the-scripture-references-where-hare-krishna-maha-mantra-is-me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is found in the Uttara Khanda of the Padma Purana:

> The wife said: O Lord, O ocean of virtues, listen to my words. If 
>   for some reason you are angry with your mother, speak out to 
>   me. O good one, formerly you never resorted to silence like this. 
>   Some younger brother has insulted you. This parrot in the cage 
>   does not eat food without you. Give him well-cooked food, so 
>   also to the sarika uttering indistinct but sweet words. **Teach the parrot and the sarika the series of names of Vishnu (like) 'Rama, 
>   Rama; Hare Krsna'**. Get up. The two are very clever. What offence have I done to you, that you are not talking to me? I have well 
>   preserved the wealth which you have given to me. O Lord, I will 
>   not wait till the delivery of your lustre (i.e. semen) that you have 
>   put into me. I shall follow you. (**Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda, Chapter 209, Verses 36b-41**)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxX89gcvNlg

Comment: But it is not 'Harekrishna Mahamantra'!

Comment: It says "Hare Krishna" explicitly. @Pratimaputra

Comment: @yes. but mahamantra means all sixteen letters. so u cd mention in answer that its not the Harekrishna mahamantra as its known.

Comment: wow excellent find

Comment: hahahaha awesome is that parrot on youtube :)

Comment: Yes. A friend gave me that video link. @brahmajijnasa

Comment: Did you know that Hare Krishna maha mantra is mentioned one more time in the Padma Purana at another place?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure. Actually, I haven't read Padma Purana much. @brahmajijnasu

Comment: I found it and posted at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34375/2790

Answer (score 1):

1. 

श्री कृष्ण उवाच युधिष्ठिर के प्रति~

रामनाम्नः परं नास्ति मोक्ष लक्ष्मी प्रदायकम्।
तेजोरुपं यद् अवयक्तं रामनाम अभिधियते।।

(श्रीमद् वाल्मीकियानंद रामायण~८/७/१६)

श्रीकृष्ण युधिष्ठिर से कहते हैं किस शास्त्र में ऐसा कोई भी मंत्र वर्णित नहीं है जो श्रीराम के नाम के बराबर हो जो ऐश्वर्य (धन) और मुक्ति दोनों देने में सक्षम हो। श्रीराम का नाम स्वयं ज्योतिर्मय नाम कहा गया है, जिसको मैं भी व्यक्त नहीं कर सकता।

2)
रामस्तवमधीयानः श्रद्धाभक्तिसमन्वितः ।
कुलायुतं समुद्धृत्य रामलोके महीयते।।

(इति पद्मपुराण, श्रीकृष्ण उवाच अर्जुन के प्रति)

जो श्रीराम से संबंध रखने वाले स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं तथा जिनकी भक्ति, विश्वास और श्रद्धा श्रीराम में सुदृढ़ है। वह लोग अपने दस सहस्त्र कुलों का उद्धार करके श्रीराम के लोक में पूजित होते है।

3)
श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~युधिष्ठिर के प्रति

मंत्रा नानाविधाः सन्ति शतशो राघवस्य च।
तेभ्यस्त्वेकं वदाम्यद्य तव मंत्रं युधिष्ठिर।।
श्रीशब्धमाद्य जयशब्दमध्यंजयद्वेयेनापि पुनःप्रयुक्तम्।
अनेनैव च मन्त्रेण जपः कार्यः सुमेधसा।

( श्रीमद् वाल्मीकियानंद रामायण, 9~7.44,45a,46a)

वैसे तो श्रीराघाव के अनेक मन्त्र हैं, किन्तु युधिष्ठिर उनमें से एक उत्तम मन्त्र मैं तुमको बतलाता हूँ । पूर्वमें श्रीराम शब्द, मध्यमें जय शब्द और अन्तमें दो जय शब्दोंसे मिला हुआ (श्रीराम जय राम जय जय राम) राममन्त्र। बुद्धिमान जनों को सिर्फ इसी मंत्र का जाप करना चाहिए।

4)
राम नाम सदा प्रेम्णा संस्मरामि जगद्गुरूम्।
क्षणं न विस्मृतिं याति सत्यं सत्यं वचो मम ॥

(श्री आदि-पुराण ~ श्री कृष्ण वाक्य अर्जुन के प्रति)

मैं ! जगद्गुरु श्रीराम के नाम का निरंतर प्रेम पूर्वक स्मरण करता रहता हूँ, क्षणमात्र भी नहीं भूलता हूँ । अर्जुन मैं सत्य सत्य कहता हूँ ।

5)
रामस्याति प्रिय नाम रामेत्येव सनातनम्।
दिवारात्रौ गृणन्नेषो भाति वृन्दावने स्थितः ।।

(श्री शुक संहिता)

श्री राम नाम भगवान राम को सबसे प्रिय नाम है और यह नाम भगवान राघव का शाश्वत नाम है। श्रीराम के इस शाश्वत नाम का जप करने से भगवान कृष्ण वृंदावन में सुशोभित होते हैं।

6)
चत्वारः पठिता वेदास्सर्वे यज्ञाश्च याजिताः ।
त्रिलोकी मोचिता तेन राम इत्यक्षर द्वयम् ।।

(पद्मपुराण ~श्री कृष्ण अर्जुन से कहते हैं)

दो अक्षर वाले श्री रामनाम का जिसने कीर्तन कर लिया, वे समझिये कि चारों वेद साङ्गोपाङ्ग पढ़ चुके, सभी यज्ञ कर चुके और उसने तीनों लोकों का उद्धार भी कर लिया।

7)सर्वपापविनिर्मुक्ता नाममात्रैकजल्पकाः ।
जानकीवल्लभस्यासि धम्नि गच्छन्ति सादरम् ॥
दुर्लभं योगिनां नित्यं स्थानं साकेतसंज्ञकम् ।
सुखपूर्वं लभेत् तन्तु नामसंराधनात् प्रिये ॥

(पद्मा पुराण~श्रीशिव का वचन मां पार्वती के प्रति)

केवल एकमात्र श्रीराम नामजप करनेवाला मनुष्य सारे पापोंसे विशेषरूपसे मुक्त होकर श्रीजानकीवल्लभ के नित्य साकेतधाम में आदरपूर्वक गमन करते हैं ।
प्रिये ! नित्य साकेत-धाम योगियोंके लिये भी दुर्लभ है । भक्तजन नामकी आराधनाके फलस्वरूप उसे सुखपूर्वक प्राप्त कर लेते हैं ।

8)
यद्दिव्यनाम स्मरतां संसारो गोष्पदायते ।
सा नव्यभक्तिर्भवति तद्रामपदमाश्रये ।।

(कलिसंतरण उपनिषद)

जिनके स्मरण मात्र से यह संसार गोपद के समान अवस्था को प्राप्त हो जाता है, उसी को नित्य किशोर रहने वाली भक्ति कहा गया है जो भगवान श्री रामचंद्र के चरणों में आश्रय प्रदान करें।

9)
रामनामजपादेव भासकोऽहं विशेषतः ।
तथैव सर्वलोकानां क्रमणे शक्तिमानहम् ॥
नामविश्रम्भहीनानां साधनान्तरकल्पना ।
कृता महर्षिभिः सर्वैः परानन्दैकनिष्टितैः ॥

(आदित्य पुराण)

भगवान सूर्यनारायण कहते है:- 'विशेषतः राम-नामका जप करने के कारण ही मैं जगत्का प्रकाशक हूँ तथा सम्पूर्ण लोकोंका पर्यटन करने में मैं समर्थ हूँ।"
‘एकमात्र परमानन्दमें स्थित सारे महर्षिगणने रामनाम में विश्वासहीन लोगोंके लिये ही अन्य साधनों की कल्पना की है ।"

10)
अशांशे रामनामश्च त्रयः सिद्धा भवन्ति हि ।
बीज मोंकार सोहं च सूत्रै रुक्तमिति श्रुतिः ॥
रामनाम्नः समुत्पन्नः प्रणवो मोक्षुदाय ।।

(श्रीमद् महारामायण पंचम सर्ग)

अर्थ:- शिव जी पार्वती जी से कहते हैं कि-सूत्र और वेद कहते कि बीज, ओंकार और सोहं यह तीनों श्रीराम नाम के प्रभा से सिद्ध होते हैं।
जो प्रणव (ॐ) मोक्ष देता है वह श्रीराम नाम से उत्पन्न हुआ है।

11)
विष्णोर्नामानि विप्रेन्द्र सर्वदेवाधिकानि वै।
तेषां मध्ये तु तत्त्वज्ञा रामनाम वरंस्मृतम्॥

~ (श्रीपद्म_पुराण ७/१५/८७)

“हे विप्रेन्द्र जैमिनि! विष्णु के सभी नाम सभी देवों से अधिक प्रभाव रखने वाले हैं, उन सभी भगवन्नामों में भी तत्त्वदर्शी महर्षियों ने राम नाम को परम माना है। ”

12)
रामेत्यक्षरयुग्मं हि सर्वं मंत्राधिकं द्विज।
यदुच्चारणमात्रेण पापी याति पराङ्गतिम्॥

~ (श्रीपद्म_पुराण ७/१५/८८)

“हे द्विज! रा-म यह दो अक्षर [का मन्त्र] सभी मन्त्रों से अधिक-श्रेष्ठ है, इसके उच्चारण मात्र से महापापी भी परम-गति को प्राप्त [ आसानी से ] प्राप्त कर लेता है।”

13)
रामनामप्रभावं हि सर्वदेवप्रपूजनम् ।
महेश एव जानाति नान्यो जानाति जैमिने॥

~ (श्रीपद्म_पुराण ७/१५/८९)

“राम नाम के प्रभाव से हीं सभी देव [ इसके अंश मात्र से ] प्रकट होकर पूज्यनीय हुए हैं, यह रहस्य तो महेश भगवान शिव ही भलीभाँति जानते हैं, अन्य नहीं जानते।

14)
सर्वश्रीरामचन्द्रेति वेदसारं परात्परम्।
येऽन्ये कृष्णादयः सर्वेऽप्यवतारा हृसंख्यकाः॥
रामस्यैव कलांशास्ते त्ववतारी रघूत्तमः।
एवं प्रमुदवनस्यैव कला वृन्दावनादयः॥
तथा सीता पराशक्तेरंशा राधाद यः स्त्रिय:।
तथा सरय्वाश्चैव कलाः श्रीसूर्य तनयादयः॥
इति श्रुत्वा गिरं व्यौमीं निष्ठ नौ समभूद् दृढा।
एव श्रीरामचन्द्रेति ध्यायतोः सुहितात्मनोः॥

[श्रीमद् आदिरामायण (१३७ / ९७-१००) ]

भगवान्‌ श्रीव्यास जी कहते हैं कि श्रीरामचन्द्र जी ही वेदों के सार रूप परात्पर परमतत्व हैं। जो कृष्णादि असंख्य हरि के अवतार हैं वे सभी श्रीरामचन्द्र जी कलांश ( एक कला के भी अंश मात्र ) हैं लेकिन रघुवर श्रीराम तो इन सबके अवतारी हैं। और श्रीप्रमोदवन की कला स्वरूप वृंदावनादि धाम हैं एवं पराशक्ति श्रीसीता जी की अंश स्वरूप राधा आदि स्त्रियां ( शक्तियां ) हैं एवं श्रीसरयू जी की कला स्वरूप श्रीसूर्य पुत्री यमुना आदि दिव्य नदियां हैं। ऐसी आकाशवाणी सुनकर श्रीराम तत्व में मेरी निष्ठा और ज्यादा बढ़ गयी और मैं स्वयं के कल्याण एवं मंगल के लिए श्रीरामचन्द्र जी का स्मरण करने लगा।

15)
अहं पूज्योऽभवं लोके श्रीमन्नामानुकीर्तनात् । अतः श्रीरामनाम्नस्तु कीर्तनं सर्वदोचितम् ॥ रामनाम परं ध्येयं ज्ञेयं पेयमहर्निशम् । सर्वदा सद्भिरित्युक्तं पूर्वं मां जगदीश्वरैः ॥
(श्रीमद् गणेश पुराण)

श्रीगणेशजी कहते हैं—“मैं श्रीमद् राम-नामका निरन्तर कीर्तन करनेके कारण ही जगत् में सर्वप्रथम पूजनीय बना हूँ । अतएव श्रीराम-नामका कीर्तन करना सदा ही वाञ्छनीय है । 'पूर्वकालमें मुझसे श्रेष्ठ जगदीश्वरोंने राम-नामको परम ध्येय, ज्ञेय तथा दिवानिशि पेय बतलाया है ।

16)
सप्तकोट्यो महामन्त्राश्चित्तविभ्रमकारकाः ।
एक एव परो मन्त्रो 'राम' इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

(मनुस्मृति)

सात करोड़ महामंत्र हैं, वे सब के सब आपके चित्तको भ्रमित करनेवाले हैं। यह दो अक्षरोंवाला 'राम' नाम परम मन्त्र है। यह सब मन्त्रोंमें श्रेष्ठ मंत्र है । सब मंत्र इसके अन्तर्गत आ जाते हैं। कोई भी मन्त्र बाहर नहीं रहता। सब शक्तियाँ इसके अन्तर्गत हैं।

17)
सीतारामात्मकं सर्वं सर्वकारणकारणम्।
अनयोरेकतातत्त्वं गुणतोरूपतोपि च ।।
द्वयोर्नित्यं द्विधारूपं तत्त्वतो नित्यमेकता।

(बृहद-विष्णु पुराण)

"Whole everything is pervaded by SītāRāma. Śrī SītāRāma are the cause of all the causes. They are in fact one and same entity, also by virtue of being equal in their qualities and beauty-elegance-charm of their divine forms.

जय जय श्री सीताराम