# Is there any any naam kirtan of Shiva?

Tags: shiva, name, bhakti, japa

Do we have any *naam-kirtan* of god Shiva similar to the *Hare Krishna* for Sri Krishna, in the shastras?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the "*Hare Krishna*" [is a Mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23667/please-provide-all-the-scripture-references-where-hare-krishna-maha-mantra-is-me) and not a Kīrtana, and the greatest Mahā-Mantra as per the Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava's.

Now, Shiva Purana defines what is meant by a Kīrtana, as follows -

> [Verse 1.4.3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225549.html), Shiva Purana
>
> गीतात्मना श्रुतिपदेन च भाषया वा शंभुप्रतापगुणरूपविलासनाम्नाम् । वाचा
> स्फुटं तु रसवत्स्तवनं यदस्य तत्कीर्तनं भवति साधनमत्र मध्यम् ॥ ३ ॥
>
> > 3. **By Kīrtana (glorification) is meant the clear expression of Śiva’s exploits, attributes, forms, sports, names etc. in good taste by
> >    reciting traditional lore, singing songs of praise even in mother
> >    tongue.** It is the middle one of the three means.

- So basically, anything that sings or talks about the glory, significance, or importance of God Shiva and his name, will constitute as an act of *Shiva-Kīrtana*, and even mother tongue is allowed in the Kīrtana.
- As such there can be several songs and other forms of glorification in various languages for Shiva. For instance, the famous Hindi Aarti - [Jai Shiva Omkara](https://youtu.be/BhwOproElxU) and, other song-playlist like [this playlist - Holy Chants On Shiva & Shakti](https://gaana.com/album/holy-chants-on-shiva-shakti-sanskrit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

> कार्यं विष्णुः क्रिया ब्रह्मा कारणं तु महेश्वरः । प्रयोजनार्थं रुद्रेण
> मूर्तिरेका त्रिधा कृता ॥ १५॥ धर्मो रुद्रो जगद्विष्णुः सर्वज्ञानं
> पितामहः ।
> **श्रीरुद्र रुद्र रुद्रेति यस्तं ब्रूयाद्विचक्षणः ॥ १६॥ कीर्तनात्सर्वदेवस्य सर्वपापैः प्रमुच्यते ।**
>
> Rudra is Dharma. Vishnu is the world. Brahma is Knowledge.
> **Therefore, do Kirtana of His name, 'Rudra', 'Rudra'. By singing like this, the hallowed name of this great Lord, all your sins will be
> destroyed.**

~ Rudrahrdayopanishat of  Krishna-Yajur-Veda. 15, 16